# Splitting one NumPy array into two arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose I have a `NumPy` `2D` array `A`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> A=np.arange(30).reshape(3,10)
>>> A
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]])
```

I need to get two arrays `B` and `C` with the following properties:

```
B = array([[ 0,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
           [10, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
           [20, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]])

C = array([[ 1,  2],
           [11, 12],
           [21, 22]])
```

**What is the easiest way to accomplish this?**

Note that I have to get all sets of `C` (2 adjacent columns) and `B` (which is `A` without `C`). I tried different `NumPy` constructs like `np.delete`, `np.hstack` but nothing seem to work at the corner conditions like in the above example.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One of the simplest ways is to use indexing to select the appropriate columns:

```
>>> A[:, [1, 2]] # choose all rows from columns 1-2 (gives C)
array([[ 1,  2],
       [11, 12],
       [21, 22]])

>>> A[:, np.r_[0, 3:10]] # choose all rows from columns 0, 3-9 (gives B)
array([[ 0,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]])
```

Alternatively, you could try `hsplit` break up `A` and then concatenate bits back together. This feels less efficient than the indexing method above though:

```
>>> splits = np.hsplit(A, [1, 3]) 
>>> B = np.hstack((splits[0], splits[2]))
>>> C = splits[1]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use array fancy indexing:

```
B = A[:, [0] + list(range(3, A.shape[1]))]
C = A[:, [1, 2]]
```

where:

- the comma separates the indices you want to take from each dimension.
- operator `:` tells to take all elements of that dimension
- using a sequence of integers will specify which elements of the corresponding dimension should be taken (ex. `[1, 2]`)

Answer (score 3):

For `C` you can use simple slicing:

```
>>> A[:,1:3]
array([[ 1,  2],
       [11, 12],
       [21, 22]])
```

For `B` use [`numpy.hstack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html) on two slices of `A`:

```
>>> np.hstack((A[:,:1], A[:,3:]))
array([[ 0,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]])
>>>
```